# intellisense jquery + external js in expression web?

Tags: jquery, intellisense, microsoft-expression-web

Can anyone tell me what i am doing wrong? I am trying to get intellisense in expression web 2 for external js and jquery

I am able to do it in visual studio 2008

I have searched google but can't seem to find the way of doing it

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know that there was a [hotfix](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/KB958502) you had to install for VS2008 to get intellisense to work with jQuery. The hotfix allows VS to parse the VS-annotated versions of the files for intellisense hints. I don't think that a similar hotfix exists for Expression Web.

Quoting from the link:

> This hotfix only applies to the
>   products Visual Studio 2008 SP1 and
>   Visual Web Developer 2008 Express
>   edition with SP1. If you try to apply
>   it to other versions of Visual Studio
>   or Visual Web Developer Express, you
>   will get an error dialog box with the
>   message.

Comment: I haven't heard of anything that works with Expression Web either.